# Why didn' t either Darth Vader or Obi-Wan use the force in their final battle?

Tags: star-wars

Why didn't either one use a force push, jump, or speed in their final battle? Were their powers no longer strong enough to use these in battle? It could have potentially been a match deciding move to use a force push or speed in this battle...

Comment: Is this why Darth said, "You're powers are weak old man..."?

Comment: because in the 1970s people's expectations of movie fights were much simpler, and the special effects technology was also much simpler.  It was only once the audience was completely ADHD that we needed CG Yoda's doing flips in fights. // also reflect that it takes the force to use a light saber at all.

Comment: @zipquincy - Precisely this. The point is that they're both creaky and tired, Obi-wan by his advanced age and Darth by decades of being confined to heavy armour. Their fight is marked by both attempting to conserve energy and consists of efficient killing strokes rather than frenetic movement.

Comment: Why then can Yoda and Dooku, and even Palpatine in the Clone Wars cartoon still execute these moves with the Force even with their advanced age? Heavy Armor would make you very much stronger after wearing it for 20 years. It would be like lifting weights everyday, you would overpower the other person easily,

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Why do the lightsaber moves of Luke Skywalker look so uncoordinated and crude compared to the prequels?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/45283/5184) The original question is focused on Luke, but the argument and many of the answers apply to all battles in the OT.

Comment: Specifically, see [Dacio's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45312/5184).

Comment: @phantom42, I read most of that , agree with some of it. So if the movie with the fight scene was remade today, there would be uses of the force due to special effects advancement? What I'm getting at is it due to their age or loss or body mass as in Vader? I basically agree with zipquincy as the real reason.

Comment: Force push/jump/speed are RPG/computer-game powers that don't actually exist in canon any more (thankfully!)  So canonically they didn't use them because they don't exist.

Comment: @Darth Satan...what? of course they are, have you seen the movies and clone wars?

Comment: Dacio's answer explains that he believes that in-universe, the fighting styles are due to the situations and make sense given the characters and their mindsets.

Comment: Why did Gunnar Södergren delete his answer? It was dead on.

Comment: @DarthSatan, well that's completely untrue.  Obi-Wan uses force push against General Grievous in the movies, he and Qui-gon use force speed in the Phantom Menace, and both he and Anakin use force jump occasionally.

Comment: You should probably specify whether this is addressing ANH or RotS :)

Comment: @Robert - actually no; there's absolutely no warrant whatsoever in the movies for the Force being expressed in terms of specifically named powers like this.  They're RPG/CG powers retrospectively applied by the EU to uses of the Force in the movies.  In the movies you just use the force to jump further, there is no "Force Jump".

Comment: @DarthSatan seriously?  They clearly use the skills, the names were created by the games.  All you gotta do is watch the movies.

Comment: @bitmask Perhaps he just wanted the Fear & Loathing hat.

Comment: @Robert - the point I'm making is that there are no individual skills.  "Using the force" is a *single* ability: the skill that you use to lift a rock is the same as the skill you use to sense your father is the same as the skill you use to tell a Stormtrooper that these aren't the droids he's looking for.  There's only one skill and it's "using the force"; the names aren't relevant, the splitting of the force into individual skills is the non-canon element.

Comment: @Darth Satan, they do all those things in the movies, your argument is null.

Comment: I'm with @DarthSatan.  Regardless of how the force is used, it is still just "using the force."  Obi-Wan did not tell Luke to "Force Sense the hole", he said "use the force."  And technically, Obi-Wan had to use the force when he was "defeated" so he could become one with the force.

Comment: Sir, you're picking knits, and you know it. You know they didn't use the force for super speed, super jumping or force pushing....

Comment: More related previous discussion: [Why are Jedi more agile in T-Canon than G-Canon?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56594/5184)

Comment: @zipquincy It does not take the force to use a light sabre. Where on earth did you get that BS from?

Answer (score 2):

**My opinion** 
First, the battle wasn't **that** long. It was basically a chat and then Kenobi kept hitting Vader's lightsaber. It was a very calm fight - If we can call it a fight. When Obi-Wan sees Luke he basically suicides and becomes one with the force. So, I don't even think It was a real fight. Obi-Wan was aged and Vader probably thought he could easily defeat him. 
Also, don't forget the movie is from the 80s - we don't have acrobatics like the prequel ones or scenes like those. Hope I helped you

Answer (score 1):

Novelizations repeatedly showed that lightsaber combat is more about using the Force than swinging around a blade.

Episode II explicitly ran into the "well, let's stop throwing fireballs at each other" with Dooku vs. Yoda.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to think when Jedi/Sith fight, they are constantly using the Force to assess their opponent and to sense any and all threats. As stated in other answers, however, since Obi-Wan had bigger plans and Vader assumed Obi-Wan would be no match for him, there was no need for acrobatics or things like Force throws. But I wouldn't assume that simply because you don't "see" the Force, it isn't there.

Comment: no, you can tell when they use the force to jump like yoda or palp do...

Comment: The Force is not just acrobatics and making objects move with your mind. It's about sensing your environment and being able to respond to it, as well. Luke saw visions and heard voices because of his connection to the Force. This is not something you could observe him doing if not for film editing.

Comment: I agree they  use the force for sensing and responding,  but those are not the force jumps, running, and pushes, you can obviously tell when they use the force to enhance those things....